# How do I click on specific text in an array of text?

Tags: pygame

I am trying to click on a specific word in an array but I can't think of how.

This is what I have:

```
  for x in range(0, len(names)):
    templine = font.render(names[x], True, WHITE)
    tempRect = templine.get_rect()
    tempRect.midleft = (50, (170+30*x))
    if mouse012[0] == True and tempRect.collidepoint(mouseXY):
      state = AppState.STATS

      detailsName = names[x]
    screen.blit(templine, tempRect)
```

Comment: what is your problem ? Do you get error message? This code seems OK but you didn't say what wrong with it. And you didn't show how you use it. BTW: If you don't move text then you could render them once at start and keep on list as pairs `[(templine, tempRect), ...]`

Comment: how do you draw elements? Maybe you draw selected text before you draw/clear background and it removes your selected text and you can't see selection. It is important to draw all elements after drawing/clearing background and before `flip()`/`update()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your problem. Code seems OK. maybe you draw it in wrong moment - before drawing/cleaning background - and it was removed and you couldn't see selection.

---

It is minimal working code.

First I use list of names to create list with all images and rectangles - because it never change.

And later I use event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to check if it was clicked in one of rectangles and I assign it to variable `selected`

And after clearing background I use `selected` to draw selection, and then I draw all text.

Using `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and `selected` I can also unselect text.
Using `mouse.get_pressed()` it makes big problem because selection is fliping.

I could also use `MOUSEBUTTONUP` to remove selection when I release button.

---

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames)

# ... empty ...

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# ... empty ...

# --- main ---

names = ['Aaaaa', 'Bbbbb', 'Ccccc', 'Ddddd']
   
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

# - create all objects -

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)

items = []

for x, name in enumerate(names):
    image = font.render(name, True, WHITE)
    rect = image.get_rect()
    rect.midleft = (50, (170+30*x))
    items.append([name, image, rect])

selected = None

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for name, image, rect in items:
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print(name)
                    if selected != (name, image, rect):
                        selected = (name, image, rect)
                    else:
                        selected = None  # unselect on click
                    break

        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        #    selected = None  # unselect when button released
        
    # - changes/moves/updates -

    # ... empty ...

    # - draws -

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if selected:
        (name, image, rect) = selected
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)
        
    for name, image, rect in items:
        screen.blit(image, rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)
    
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

And almost the same with `pygame.mouse` - but without unselection because flick selection and would need much more work.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames)

# ... empty ...

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# ... empty ...

# --- main ---

names = ['Aaaaa', 'Bbbbb', 'Ccccc', 'Ddddd']
   
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

# - create all objects -

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)

items = []

for x, name in enumerate(names):
    image = font.render(name, True, WHITE)
    rect = image.get_rect()
    rect.midleft = (50, (170+30*x))
    items.append([name, image, rect])

selected = None

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        
    # - changes/moves/updates -

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for name, image, rect in items:
            if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print(name)
                if selected != (name, image, rect):
                    selected = (name, image, rect)
                #else:
                #    selected = None  # unselect on click
                break
    #else:
    #    selected = None  # unselect when button released
        
    # - draws -

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    if selected:
        (name, image, rect) = selected
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)
        
    for name, image, rect in items:
        screen.blit(image, rect)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)
    
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with class `Text()`

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames)

class Text():
    
    def __init__(self, text, x, y, font, color=WHITE):
        self.image = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.midleft = (x, y)
        self.selected = False    
            
    def draw(self, screen):
        if self.selected:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    
    def is_clicked(self, pos):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pos)
        
    def toggle(self):
        self.selected = not self.selected
        
# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# ... empty ...

# --- main ---

names = ['Aaaaa', 'Bbbbb', 'Ccccc', 'Ddddd']
   
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

# - create all objects -

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)

all_items = []

for x, name in enumerate(names):
    text = Text(name, 50, (170+30*x), font)
    all_items.append(text)

previous_selected = None

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for text in all_items:
                if text.is_clicked(event.pos):
                    #text.toggle()
                    #break
                    #if previous_selected == text:
                    if text.selected:
                        # unselect current item
                        text.selected = False
                        previous_selected = None
                    else:
                        if previous_selected:
                           # unselect previous item
                           previous_selected.selected = False
                        # select current item
                        text.selected = True
                        previous_selected = text
                    break
                    
        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        #    if previous_selected:
        #         previous_selected.selected = False
        #         previous_selected = None  # unselect when button released
        
    # - changes/moves/updates -

    # ... empty ...
    
    # - draws -

    screen.fill(BLACK)
        
    for text in all_items:
        text.draw(screen)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)
    
# - end -

pygame.quit()
```